# Bi invariant Riemannian metric on a Lie Group

Tags: gr.group-theory, mg.metric-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

I'm trying to find an example of a Lie group $G$ which admits a bi-invariant Riemannian metric, and which has a closed subgroup $H$ such that the manifold $G/H$ does not admit a $G$-invariant Riemannian metric.

I know so far that if $G/H$ admits an invariant Riemannian metric, then $H$ has to be compact. So I'm searching for a Lie group $G$ which admits a bi-invariant Riemannian metric and a closed subgroup $H$ which is not compact, since this will solve the problem. Does anyone know such group?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: If $G$ admits a biinvariant Riemannian metric $ds^2$, then projection fo $ds^2$ to $G/H$ is left-invariant under the action of $G$. As for your other question, think about abelian groups.

Comment: So the first claim is true even if H is not compact @Misha ?

Comment: That's what I wrote. On the other hand, very few connected Lie groups admit biinvariant metrics: products of abelian and compact groups.

Comment: @user42999: your statement "if $G/H$ has invariant Riem. metric then $H$ is compact" is false. 2 counterexamples: (1) $G$ not compact, $H=G$; (2) $G$ arbitrary, $H$ any infinite discrete subgroup: this second example shows that your statement is false even if $G$ acts faithfully on $G/H$.